# Date other than today and yesterday not showing up correctly with moment.calendar

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I am using moment.js and have the below code in angularJS that displays dates. If the date is Today and Yesterday it works well.
For example: If today's date is 2/6/2015, it displays correctly as Today and for 2/5/2015 it displays correctly as Yesterday.
**But if the date is 2/4/2015 it is showing up as 2015-02-04T11:20:00-06:00 and not as the way I want**. If the date is 01/28/2015 it formats correctly as specified in sameElse. I thought the sameElse should have taken care of the days that are not today and yesterday.
I am getting the date from the server in utc format. Example: 02/05/2015 18:01:04:946

What am I missing?

Here is the code:

### controller:

```
$scope.calDate = function(val) {
    var d_val = moment(val + ' +0000','MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss:SSS Z').format('LLL');
    moment.locale('en', {
        'calendar' : {
            lastDay : '[Yesterday]',
            sameDay : '[Today]',
            sameElse : 'MMM D, YYYY'
       }
    });
    return moment(new Date(d_val)).calendar();
}
```

### html:

```
<div>{{calDate(list.dateVal)}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 moment.locale('en', longDateFormat : {
        LT : 'MMM D YYYY'
    },
  'calendar' : {
            lastDay : '[Yesterday]',
            sameDay : '[Today]',
            sameElse : 'LT'
       }
    });
```

Comment: I tried this. But all the dates are showing up as 'Invalid date'

Comment: Invalid date :-( .try 'LT' default time for calender

Comment: No luck. Still gives me Invalid date